# How can I modify a remote library defined on import_map.json?

Tags: typescript, deno

I'm having a difficult time trying to work with deno and its imports. Right now I have the following definition on my import_map.json:

```
{
    "imports": {
        "deno-slack-sdk/": "https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_sdk@2.5.0/",
        "deno-slack-api/": "https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_api@2.1.2/"
    }
}
```

I want to edit the functions that were imported by these libs like when we enter in a node_modules folder and edit its files, but these files don't exist in my pc. How can I do that?

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73596356/438273) at the linked duplicate target question. It describes using the command [`deno vendor`](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/vendor), which exists for this purpose.